# python, importing a file with a dynamic name

Tags: python

Folks, I would like to import python files, and functions dynamically.  The modulenames should be passed to a function like so:

```
def scrape(url, foo):
    modulename = url['modulename']
    import modulename
    modulename.modulename(url, foo)
```

This is erroring out with:

```
ImportError: No module named modulename
```

So how can we get python to use 'modulename' as a variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [importlib.import_module()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module):

```
def scrape(url, foo):
    import importlib
    modulename = importlib.import_module(url["modulename"])
    modulename.modulename(url, foo)
```

Comment: great, now... its not translating the dynamic function name.  how do i get around that?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
module = __import__('module_name')
```

Example:

```
module = __import__('math')
print module.sqrt(4)
>> 2
```

Or, if you want to use a dynamic method name as well

```
module = __import__('math')
method =  getattr(module, 'sqrt')
method(4)
>> 2
```

Comment: How would i call the functions defined in that module?

Comment: To use with math.sqrt: `module = __import__('math'); module.sqrt(2)`

Comment: so the function name cant be dynamically passed as well?  i guess i can resort to main()

Comment: Of course it can, see my updated answer :)